# Stochastic differential equation with complicated Brownian noise term

Tags: stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a stochastic differential equation for a position $x$ with respect to time $t$
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} t} = F[x(t), t] + \beta^\star(t) $$
where $F$ is a linear function of $x$ and $t$ (more precicely $F = a t - b x$) and interestingly $\beta^\star$ is a Brownian noise term with variance proportional to the velocity $v(t) = \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} t}$.

I would like to rewrite this in terms of the velocity by differentiating with respect to time $t$
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{\mathrm{d} F}{\mathrm{d} t} + \frac{\mathrm{d} \beta^\star(t)}{\mathrm{d} t} $$
where naturally $\frac{\mathrm{d} F}{\mathrm{d} t} = a - b v$, but I'm don't know how to deal with the variance of the last term. It should be a white noise term, but with which variance?

I tried to apply the Itô differential here but didn't get far as the idea seems to be that the variance of $\beta^\star$ should be constant. What should I do here?

EDIT: So essentially my first equation (I changed to the notation $\beta^\star$ for the Brownian noise with variance $c v$) could be rewritten to
$$ v = F[x(t), t] + \sqrt{c v} \beta = a t - b x + \sqrt{c v} \beta $$
where $c$ is a constant and $\beta$ Brownian noise term with unit variance. I would like to transform this into the Itô form
$$ \mathrm{d} v = (a - b v) \mathrm{d} t + L[v(t), t] \mathrm{d} \beta $$
but don't know how to get to the function $L$.

User @gt6989b suggested that I consider
$$ \mathrm{d} v = (a-bv) \mathrm{d} t + \frac{v}{Z} \mathrm{d} B_t $$
where the variance of $\mathrm{d} B_t$ is $Z^2$. I get the part that $\mathrm{d} B_t / Z$ would have variance 1 but don't understand how he has arrived to the $v$ in the last term. Comparing this to my equation would yield $$ L[v(t), t] \mathrm{d} \beta = \frac{v}{Z} \mathrm{d} B_t$$ which I think would imply that $L = v$?

Comment: if the variance is proportional to the velocity, how do you handle negative velocity? Variance cannot go negative.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. However in the case I'm considering I only study the part where the velocity is positive.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** If the variance of $dB_t$ is $Z^2(t)$, then I would consider the SDE as
$$
dv = (a - bv)dt + \frac{v}{Z(t)} dB_t
$$
where the deterministic term would give you your equation without the white noise, the variance of $\frac{dB_t}{Z(t)}$ is $1$

Comment: I don't really understand the hint here (added an edit to the original question). I would appreciate any further help, thanks!

Comment: @655321 yes, I agree with what you wrote in the update to the question.